# How do i require jquery ui draggable containment to be relative to parent?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have the following problem: http://jsfiddle.net/DerNa/12/

Which is demonstrated more clearly the "jump" here: http://jsfiddle.net/DerNa/11/

Basically, what is happening is that the containment is relative to the window (in this case the frame, demonstrated by offset the parent 200px), and that is undesirable. Is it at all possible to get it to be relative to the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per the docs use

```
containment:'parent'
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment

Look on "Options tab"

Comment: it doesn't work in this case, since the image is larger than container

Comment: OK..wrap another element around image, position it and size it so it is the parent and can drag image all around as much as is needed

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It works, although i didn't end up going this route, because i need a bit more customization anyways. i ended up listening for drag event and manually adjusting the ui.position values